# Cannot invoke 'subscript' with an argument type

Tags: swift, xcode6

I am new to Xcode and Swift. I am using Xcode 6 and I am getting the following error:

> "Cannot invoke 'subscript' with an argument of type '@lvalue String'

Here is the code:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
  dataSecond = []
  if textField.text = "" {
    search = false
    self.tableView?.reloadData()
  } else {
    for i in names {
      if(i["business_name"] as String).lowercaseString.findInString(textField.text) {
        self.dataSecond.addObject(i)
      }
    }
    search = true
    self.tableView?.reloadData()
  }
  return false
}
```

Please let me know if you need anything else to help me solve this. Thanks!!

Comment: the compiler doesn't know what "`i`" is.  What is it?  A Dictionary?

Comment: Yes. Maybe I am doing this all wrong. "names" is the array that I retrieved from the DB for the field "business_name" -

Comment: Crap i didn't finish my comment. lol I am creating a search with a UITextField. I need to check for what is typed in the search for the array "names"

Comment: you still didn't say what "`i`" is.

Comment: I am following this tutorial online and they didn't declare what "i" is so I am guessing that is what I need to do?

Comment: where's this online tutorial?  what code snippet are you looking at?

Comment: It looks like 'names' is array of String and at this case it have no subscript syntaxis, you need do your action without subscript, 'i.lowercaseString...'

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jZWoBOu9XQM  I am using this tutorial to create the search. I have already created the table with the values from the DB

Comment: Thank you! @alex_p - that got rid of the error.